# Deshabilitar permanentemente un botón hasta que se cumpla una condicion

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo deshabilitar un botón con PHP, y que este solo se habilite cuando en el input teclee 'hola'? y de esta se ejecute mi evento. Casi me funciona, pero no se que ocurre.

```js
function comprobar() {
    if (this.value != 'hola'){
        var pagar = document.getElementById('botones');
        pagar.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<br>
<img class='paypal' src='fotos/paypal.png'/>
<input type='text' name='clave' onkeyup='comprobar()' />

<form action='pagado.php' method='post'>
    <p>
        <span>
            <input id='botones' type='submit' value='Pagar' onclick='return comprar()' />
        </span>
    </p>
</form>
<br>
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es que el boton este deshabilitado si no hay nada escrito?

Comment: Si, y que solo se habilite con 'hola', si se teclea otra cosa distinta ha de seguir deshabilitado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No ocupas de PHP sino de JS para poder manipular dichos nodos, considero debes proceder de este modo:

- Al `button` le aplicas a nivel de HTML el atributo `disabled` para que por defecto este deshabilitado
- Obtienes por medio de su `id` al `input`
- Una vez que tienes en una variable el `input`, vas a usar el evento `keyup` para revisar lo que el usuario escribe a medida que suelta cada tecla que presiona
- Verificas si de dicha variable su propiedad `value` es igual a **hola**
- De resultar ciento lo anterior, entonces colocas en `false` la propiedad disabled del `button` que recuperamos por medio de su `id` y en caso negativo es decir que no se cumpla, entonces mantienes como `true` la propiedad `disabled`

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="condicion" />
    <button disabled id="pago">Pagar</button>
    <script>
        let activador = document.getElementById("condicion")
        activador.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
          if(activador.value === "hola"){
            document.getElementById("pago").disabled = false
          }else{
            document.getElementById("pago").disabled = true
          }
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: y en caso de tener otro botón, en el cual al hacer el tercer click este se desactive, sería así? echo "<input id='botones' type='submit' name='enviar' value='añadir a carrito'/><br><br>";?>
    <script>
        var cantidad=document.getElementById('botones')
        cantidad.addEventListener('onmousedown',()=>{
          if(cantidad.value>3){
            document.getElementById('botones').disabled=true
          }
        })
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que capturar el valor del `input` y comparar.  Algo asi:

```html
<script>
    function comprobar() {
        var clave = document.getElementById('clave');
        var pagar = document.getElementById('botones');
        pagar.disabled = true;
        if (clave.value == "hola"){            
            pagar.disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
<br>
<img class='paypal' src='fotos/paypal.png'/>
<input type='text' name='clave' id='clave' onkeyup='comprobar()' />

<form action='pagado.php' method='post'>
    <p>
        <span>
            <input id='botones' type='submit' value='Pagar' onclick='return comprar()' disabled />
        </span>
    </p>
</form>
<br>
```